# Java Nested For Loop Patterns (help)

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

AAAAAAAAAX

AAAAAAAAXX

AAAAAAAXXX

AAAAAAXXXX

AAAAAXXXXX

AAAAXXXXXX

AAAXXXXXXX

AAXXXXXXXX

AXXXXXXXXX

I need to print out this pattern using nested for loops. I have it completed, but for some reason, it adds an extra line of "X" at the bottom. Any help would be much appreciated.

My Code (Please note all variables have been declared and there is no errors with the code. I just need to find a way to stop the last line of "X"s):

```
size = 10;
for(row = 1; row <= size; row++) {
  for(col = size; col > row; col--) {
    System.out.print("A");
  }
  for(col = 1; col <= row; col++) {
    System.out.print("X");
  }   
  System.out.println(); //Creates a new row.
}
```

(Edit: The code at the top appeared wrong so I fixed the format.)

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
for(row = 1; row <= size; row++) {
```

with

```
for(row = 1; row < size; row++) {
```

Then output:

```
AAAAAAAAAX
AAAAAAAAXX
AAAAAAAXXX
AAAAAAXXXX
AAAAAXXXXX
AAAAXXXXXX
AAAXXXXXXX
AAXXXXXXXX
AXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change an outer loop to iterate up to size:

```
for(row = 1; row < size; row++) {
```